# How to check menu item are already added in onprepareoptionsmenu

Tags: android, eclipse, menuitem

I m using like this way how to check it menu item already exits in onprepareoptionsmenu
Please Help me out

I m doing this programatically

Thanks in advance

```
        if(flag){                
        menu.add(0, 9, 0, "search").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS|MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Hindi").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "English").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Gujarati").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 4, 0, "Punjabi").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 5, 0, "Bengali").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 6, 0, "Marathi").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 7, 0, "Talugu").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add(0, 8, 0, "Tamil").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

     flag=false;

     SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);         
     mSearchView=new SearchView(getBaseContext());
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));           
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);              
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));     
        mSearchView.setQuery("", false);//
        mSearchView.setIconified(true); //


    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203790/how-to-check-whether-the-menu-item-already-exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 menu.add(0, 9, 0, "search")
```

here 9 is id for added item you can get it by

```
menu.findItem(9)
```

Comment: menu.findItem(9) return MenuItem if it not exist it will return null

Answer (score 2):

get the item by using and add want you want to do.hope this will work

```
 if(menu.findItem(1) !=null )
```

{

```
} else
```

{

```
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
 menu.add(0, 4, 0, "Punjabi") // here 4 is the id through which you will retrieve menu item
```

and while retrieving menu item check if it's null or not. like this

```
 MenuItem item = menu.findItem(4)
 if(item == null ) {
 // do something here Like you can add menuitem if it has not been added before
 } else {
 // do whatever you want to do with this menu item.
 }
```